# 10k Concurrent connections with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a 32GB, i7 core processor running on windows 10 and I am trying to generate 10kVU concurrent load via jmeter. For some reason I am unable to go beyond 1k concurrent and I start getting BindException error or Socket connection error. Can someone help me with the settings to achieve that kind of load? Also if someone is up for freelancing I am happy to consider that as well. Any help would be great as I am nearing production and am unable to load test this use case. If you guys have any other tools that I can use effectively, that would also help.

Answer (score 0):

You reach the limit of 1 computer, thus you must execute in distributed environment of multiple computers.

You can setup JMeter's [distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)  on your own environment or use [blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter) or other cloud based load testing tool

> we can use BlazeMeter, which provides us with an easy way to handle our load tests. All we need to do is to upload our JMX file to BlazeMeter. We can also upload a consolidated CSV file with all the necessary data and BlazeMeter will take care of splitting it, depending on the amount of engines we have set.
>
> On BlazeMeter we can set the amount of users or the combination of engines (slave systems) and threads that we want to apply to our tests. We can also configure additional values like multi locations.

Comment: Blazemeter is quite expensive. I have considered that as a last resort. Need to try every possible option before that

Answer (score 0):

1k concurrent sounds low enough that it's something else ... it's also the default amount of open file descriptor limits on a lot of Linux distributions so maybe try to raise the limit.

```
ulimit -Sn
```

will show you your current limit and

```
ulimit -Hn
```

will show you the hard limit you can go before you have to touch configuration files. Editing /etc/security/limits.conf as root and setting something like

```
yourusername soft nofile 50000
yourusername hard nofile 50000
```

yourusername - will have to be the username of the user which with you run jmeter.

After this you will probably have to restart in order for the changes to take effect. If not on Linux I don't know how to actually do this you will have to google :D

**Recommendation:**
As a [k6](https://k6.io/) developer I can propose it as an alternative tool, but running 10k VUs on a single machine will be hard with it as well. Every VU will take some memory - like at least 1-3mb and this will go up the larger your script is. But with 32gb you could still run upto 1-2kVUs and use [http.batch](https://docs.k6.io/docs/batch-requests) to make concurrent requests which might simulate the 10k VUs depending on what your actual workflow is like.

I managed to run the [stages sample](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/blob/master/samples/stages.js) with 300VUs on a single 3770 i7 CPU and 4gb of ram in a virtual machine and got 6.5k+ rps to another virtual machine on a neighboring physical machine (the latency is very low) so maybe 1.5-2kVUs with a a somewhat more interesting script and some higher latency as this will give time to the golang to actually run GC while waiting for tcp packets. I highly recommend using [discardResponseBodies](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/blob/master/release%20notes/v0.23.0.md#k6http-new-options-to-discard-the-response-body-or-to-specify-its-type-742-and-749) if you don't need them and even if you need some to actually get the response for them. This helps a lot with the memory consumption a each VU